# Hiding past relationships

Tags: marriage

Is hiding past relationships a sin? Like if women lie before marriage because if she reveals it, she won't get married. Or if a man hides his past relationships and marries a clean women, for getting married.
Can one avoid these out in any way, like through rituals or any from or sacrifices. Their was an article saying when a man/women marry in front of sacred fire and rituals, they will share thier sins.

Comment: As per scriptures , hiding is least of your concern. In general one should not be in relationship before marriage

Comment: I don't have a partner, but do feel bad if I end up with one. But this is for educational purpose, after all these are now happening, shouldn't we educate people It's WRONG, if it is? After all this subject to cheating and hurting someone else( forget about me, take it as general), and hurting someone verbally or physically is a wrong isn't it, I only want to learn, sir.

Comment: @Archit, Bhai kyu question close karva raha hai, Rahul, ko kuch clarification chaiye, Pata ho to de do bhai, kya halla machaya hua hai!!

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it is a sin.
For both men and women.

[Manu Smriti 9](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/manu/manu09.htm)

> 72. Though (a man) may have accepted a damsel in due form, he may abandon (her if she be) blemished, diseased, or deflowered, and (if she have been) given with fraud.

If a woman is not virgin, and she hides it before marriage, the marriage can be 'annuled'. There is only 1 marriage for women (barring rare exceptions).

For men, it is slightly different. They have to be brahmachari (virgin/celibate) until their 1st marriage. And this rule doesn't just mean not having sex with a woman. It includes all forms of sexual thoughts/practices (porn/masturbation etc.)

[Manu Smriti 11](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/manu/manu11.htm)

> 121. Those who know the Veda declare that a voluntary effusion of semen by a twice-born (youth) who fulfils the vow (of studentship
>      constitutes) a breach of that vow.
> 122. The divine light which the Veda imparts to the student, enters, if he breaks his vow, the Maruts, Puruhuta (Indra), the teacher (of
>      the gods, Brihaspati) and Pavaka (Fire).
> 123. When this sin has been committed, he shall go begging to seven houses, dressed in the hide of the (sacrificed) ass, proclaiming his
>      deed.
> 124. Subsisting on a single (daily meal that consists) of the alms obtained there and bathing at (the time of) the three savanas
>      (morning, noon, and evening), he becomes pure after (the lapse of) one
>      year.

Comment: It is written that vow is broken when a twice born man voluntarily effuses semen and the vedic knowledge doesn't enter him . 
But I don't think a man who has voluntarily effuses semen becomes unfit for marriage.